# Avoid overlapping css grid elements

Tags: css, css-grid

Trying to use grid for layout and I'd like to have different behavior between smaller and larger viewports. On larger viewports I want some content to be shown in a sidebar and tried using grid for this.

How can I prevent the overlapping of the `First Card` and `Second Card` when using `grid-area` like this?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar main"
  ;
    max-width: 40rem;
  
  margin: 10rem auto;
  
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.cards {
  grid-area: main;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sidebar-content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
  
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      First card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-content">
    Sidebar Content
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      Second card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Third Card
    </div>
 </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out something that works.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar first-quote"
    "sidebar quotes"
  ;
    max-width: 40rem;
  
  margin: 10rem auto;
  
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.second-row {
  grid-area: quotes;
}

.first-row {
  grid-area: first-quote;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.sidebar-content {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
  
  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="card">
      First card
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-content card">
    Sidebar Content
  </div>
  <div class="second-row">
    <div class="card">
      Second card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Third Card
    </div>
 </div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```